# Pulling data from MySQL into an Elgg application

Tags: php, mysql, events, elgg

I'm trying to use Elgg as a starting point for a certain type of social media website. One of the main things I'd like to do is allow users to create events and then display all the events in a sortable table (sortable by different attributes given to the event during the creation like date and title). For the event creation aspect, I'm using the plugin Event Manager.

I'm assuming the best way to do this is to pull the event data from where ever it is stored and put it into an HTML table (I'm using the jQuery TableSorter code). Can anyone give me a good idea of where and how to start doing this?

The biggest problem I'm having is finding where the event data is stored in MySQL.

Comment: Assuming events are created and stored by Elgg itself, is there not an event API inside Elgg? If there is, I imagine it is documented on the Elgg site?

Comment: Unfortunately event creation is not a native feature in Elgg, it's only available in a user made plug in called Event Manager

Comment: Ah righto. Have you looked in your Elgg database to see if that plugin creates its own tables? I would imagine it would store them in the same database rather than a new one.

Comment: Plugins are discouraged from creating custom tables. Storage is provided via the framework api and event manager is using it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, any info on how I could begin pulling the data from the framework api then?

Answer (score 0):

For the database organisation and model, read:

- http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/DataModel
- http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/DatabaseSchema

For fetching the data, consider using:
http://reference.elgg.org/1.8/engine_2lib_2metadata_8php.html#aec4b6f0b9565e3554acb9b39ef34a2ac
With options `order_by` and `order_by_metadata` for chosen information.